# How to use Python and .NET/C# to automatise Princeton Instruments LightField

Tags: c#, python, .net, matlab, python.net

I want to use Python to control a proprietary spectroscopic software (Princeton Instruments LightField). I have a LightField automation example using Matlab. The example use .NET to control LightField using provided DLLs.

I used [pythonnet](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet) to load the DLLs into Python, but I failed to communicate with LightField.

Here is a (non-)working example :

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r"C:\Program Files\Princeton Instruments\LightField")
sys.path.append(r"C:\Program Files\Princeton Instruments\LightField\AddInViews")

import clr
clr.AddReference('PrincetonInstruments.LightFieldViewV4')
clr.AddReference('PrincetonInstruments.LightField.AutomationV4')
clr.AddReference('PrincetonInstruments.LightFieldAddInSupportServices')

import PrincetonInstruments.LightField.AddIns as AddIns
from PrincetonInstruments.LightField.Automation import Automation

instance = Automation(True,[])
```

And here is the error message :

```
File "D:/python/test_lightfield.py", line 21, in <module> instance = Automation(True,[])
TypeError: no constructor matches given arguments
```

However, when I look at the beginning of help(Automation) :

```
help(Automation)
Help on class Automation in module PrincetonInstruments.LightField.Automation:

class Automation(System.Object)
 |  Void .ctor(Boolean, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String])
 |  
 |  Method resolution order:
 |      Automation
 |      System.Object
 |      builtins.object
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __call__(self, /, *args, **kwargs)
 |      Call self as a function.
```

or the relevant Matlab example file :

```
out.automation = PrincetonInstruments.LightField.Automation.Automation(visible,[]);
```

It looks like I instantiated the Automation class with valid arguments (a boolean and an empty string).
I don't have much documentation apart my Matlab sample file.

What am I doing wrong ?

EDIT : This was a problem of type. Using a .NET type list instead a Python list works.

```
from PrincetonInstruments.LightField.Automation import Automation
from System.Collections.Generic import List
from System import *
l = List[String]()
instance = Automation(True,l)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for supported constructor signatures in `__overloads__`, e.g.:

```
>>> import clr
>>> from System import Decimal
>>> Decimal.__overloads__
System.Decimal(Int32[])
System.Decimal(UInt64)
System.Decimal(UInt32)
System.Decimal(Int64)
System.Decimal(Int32)
System.Decimal(Single)
System.Decimal(Double)
System.Decimal(Int32, Int32, Int32, Boolean, Byte)
```

EDIT:

Convert your second argument to .NET type (`System.Collections.Generic.List[System.String]`) before passing it. Auto-conversion of containers is not supported in pythonnet yet.

EDIT:

Here is how to do this:

In C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ListInConstr
{
    public class ListInConstr
    {
        public ListInConstr(bool test1, List<String> test2)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Compile this into DLL:

`csc.exe /target:library ListInConstr.cs`

In Python:

```
>>> import clr
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append(r"C:\Debug")
>>> clr.AddReference("ListInConstr")
<System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly object at 0x02849E50>
>>> from ListInConstr import ListInConstr
>>> ListInConstr.__overloads__
ListInConstr.ListInContr(Boolean, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String])
>>> from System.Collections.Generic import List
>>> from System import String
>>> arg2=List[String]() #do not add elements here
>>> ListInConstr(True,arg2)
<ListInConstr.ListInConstr object at 0x0284E890>
>>>
```

Comment: Here is the output of Automation.__overloads__
Out[4]: PrincetonInstruments.LightField.Automation.Automation(Boolean, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String])

Comment: Convert your second argument to .NET type (System.Collections.Generic.List[System.String]) before passing it. Auto-conversion of containers is not supported in pythonnet yet.

Comment: Sorry to be heavy, but how do I do that ? If I first do import System and then instance = Automation(True, System.Collections.Generic.List[System.String]) it gives me another error message. (ArgumentException: Impossible de convertir l'objet de type 'System.RuntimeType' en type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]'.) (Sorry for the french, it says it cannot convert the System.RunTime Type into the second Collections.Generic.List type...)

Comment: I added example in my answer. Note that you cannot add items to `List<>` at construction time in pythonnet. Add items to `List<>` after instantiation.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I struggle with the python example, because this line :  clr.AddReference(r"C:\Debug\ListInConstr") doesn't work, but you help me to show the way, I hope to find a solution. Many thanks !

Comment: That line works when running Python code in interactive interpreter and DLL is located in  "C:\Debug\ListInConstr.DLL". But normally you need append the directory of DLL to sys.path - sys.path.append(r"C:\Debug"). Then add ref to it: clr.AddReference("ListInConstr").

Comment: I'm running on Windows 7 64 bits, with .NET Framework 4.6.1 installed, and I don't have the C:\Debug directory or the ListInConstr.dll on my C:\ harddrive. Google don't give any answer for that dll neither.

Comment: You need to compile the above c# code into ListInConstr.dll using Visual Studio or command-line compiler CSC.exe: `csc /target:library ListInConstr.cs`.

Comment: I found a working solution (see edited question). Thanks for your help !